# Randomly assigning a set of macros to a new set of macros

Tags: sas

I am modifying a segment of a program and what I need to do is to randomly assign a group of macros to a different set of macros in each iteration of a loop (without replacement). So, for example, suppose I have

```
%let groupa = a
%let groupb = b
%let groupc = c
%let group1 = &groupa;
%let group2 = &groupb;
%let group3 = &groupc;
```

In this case I just assigned to group1, group2, and group3 to groupa, groupb, and groupc, but what I want is on each iteration of a loop, group1, group2, and group3 are randomly assigned, without replacement, to groupa, groupb, or groupc. So maybe the next iteration is instead

```
%let group1 = &groupc;
%let group2 = &groupa;
%let group3 = &groupb;
```

Thank you in advance for any ideas on how to do this and let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a really, really bad idea, as it sounds like something you can do much more efficiently in data/proc steps.  I would suggest explaining more of why you want to do this, and we can elaborate a more effective overall solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
data rand;
do i=1 to 3;
   r =ranuni(0);
   output;
end;
run;
proc sort data=rand; by r; run;

data _null_;
set rand;
format group $6.;
group = catt("group",i);
if _n_ = 1 then
   call symput(group,"&groupa");
else if _n_ = 2 then 
   call symput(group,"&groupb");
else
   call symput(group,"&groupc");
run;
%put group1: &group1;
%put group2: &group2;
%put group3: &group3;
```

This will randomly assign A, B, and C to the groupX variables.  The Seed value of 0 ensures you get a new set each time.

Comment: Glad to help.  If it answers your question, please mark it so.